# Fundamental theorem of algebra for sedenions

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

The [Eilenberg–Niven theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Niven_theorem) generalizes the fundamental theorem of algebra for quaternionic polynomials,¹ and this theorem was further generalized to also encompass octonionic polynomials.²

Does similar theorem holds for the [sedenion algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion)?

*References*:

[1] *Eilenberg, Samuel; Niven, Ivan*, [**The “fundamental theorem of algebra” for quaternions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1944-08125-1), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 50, 246–248 (1944). [ZBL0063.01228](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.01228).

[2] *Jou, Yuh-Lin*, The ‘fundamental theorem of algebra’ for Cayley numbers, Sci. Record, Acad. Sinica 3, 29–33 (1950). [ZBL0039.26701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0039.26701).

Edit: This question is indeed answered in the negative (see the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404342/fundamental-theorem-of-algebra-for-sedenions#comment1203293_404342) of user49822). Of course the sedenion algebra has zero divisors, f.i. $a = e_1+e_{10}$. But each $x \in \mathbb{S} \setminus \{0\}$ has an inverse $1/x = \bar{x}/\|x\|^2$ with $x \cdot 1/x = 1/x \cdot x = 1$. In particular $1/a = -a/2$.

Comment: Let $a$ be a zero divisor in sedenions, then $ax-1$ has no roots, so the obvious generalization doesn't hold.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks! I didn't recall that sedenions had zero divisors... ‍♂️

Comment: @Tadashi: The comment from Wojowu doesn't seem to be quite correct. Let $a = e_1+e_{10}$. Then $a$ is a zero divisor, but with $x = -a/2$ we get $ax-1=0$. Of course there is no obvious generalization.

Comment: Wojowu's comment is easily fixed: if $a$ is a zero divisor, then the linear map $x\mapsto ax$ has a nontrivial kernel, hence is not surjective, which means that there is some $b$ for which $ax-b$ has no roots

Comment: @user49822 Thank you. Of course your argument is simple and correct.